# Aligning rotation from a imu9250 to a game object

Tags: unity, orientation, arduino

I am experimenting with interfacing unity with real world inputs, specifically I have an imu9250, connected to an arduino clone providing rotation inputs ( either quaternion or pitch/yaw/roll) to unity.   (I’m using the DMP functionality of the 9250 to calculate orientation).

The connectivity (over serial for now) works fine, rotating my sensor rotates my game object but I can’t work out how to align my input (programmatically) so that the rotation of the game object rotates in the same direction (in game space).

Any tips/pointers appreciated.

Additional information:
[image: picture of mpu9250]

[image: 9250 Coordinate System]

My understanding is that the DMP only uses the Gryo and Accelerometer, not the magnetometer.

I can’t find any other references to the coordinate system used outside of the images above. Not mentions in the data sheet as far as I could see 
http://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, here is how I solved it (for my needs at least).

This solution requires the target object have an parent GameObject (child position offset 0,0,0).  Both must be specified as parameters to the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;


public class playerController : MonoBehaviour {


    public string COMPort = "COM3";
    public int baudRate = 115200;

    //rotate input - X by 90, Y by 90
    private Quaternion offset = new Quaternion();
    public Vector3 offsetEuler = new Vector3(90, 90, 0);

    public Transform target;
    public Transform targetParent;

    public bool calibrate = true;
    private Quaternion calibrationAngle = new Quaternion();
    public bool reverse = false;

    SerialPort stream;

    void Start () {
        stream = new SerialPort(COMPort, baudRate); //Set the port and the baud rate
        stream.Open();

        // Set the offset 
        offset = Quaternion.Euler(offsetEuler);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Quaternion rawInput;
        string value = stream.ReadLine(); //Read the information
        string[] vec3 = value.Split(','); //Arduino returns a Quaternion, note however the order is different to Unity
        if (vec3[0] != "" && vec3[1] != "" && vec3[2] != "" && vec3[3] != "") //Check if all values are recieved
        {

            rawInput = new Quaternion(float.Parse(vec3[1]), float.Parse(vec3[2]), float.Parse(vec3[3]), float.Parse(vec3[0])); 

            if (calibrate)
            {
               // resets the child oritentation so that it remains consistent with world
               // needs to be sampled prior to setting parent and set afterwards.
               // this could be probably be done cleaner in the Start function
               calibrationAngle = target.transform.rotation ;
               calibrate = false;
               targetParent.transform.rotation = offset * rawInput;
                target.transform.rotation = calibrationAngle;
            }
            targetParent.transform.rotation = offset * rawInput;
        }
    }        
}
```